# Why I can't add a script-code into theme-settings without 403-forbidden?

Tags: headers

we (my son and me) modified a script - '/js/sticky-menu.js' - and it only works when Cloudflare 'Rocket Loader' is off.

Following the [tutorial](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168056-What-does-Rocket-Loader-do-) for Rocket Loader I tried to exclude the script by adding this code into the header (using theme settings of Genesis):

```
<script data-cfasync="false" src="/javascript.js"></script>
```

I modified the code to

```
<script data-cfasync="false" src="/js/sticky-menu.js"></script>
```

After saving the code I got this warning-message:

> 403 Forbidden
>
> A potentially unsafe operation has been detected in your request to this site.

Also using the complete path of the script doesn't work.

Here is the URL of my [website](https://www.jungvital.com).

Have you a solution for this problem?

kind regards,
Rainer Brumshagen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution:

Because the theme JavaScript is not in:

```
/js/sticky-menu.js
```

Rather, it's in your theme folder (as your theme name is `lifestyle-pro`, as found from your site's HTML):

```
/wp-content/themes/lifestyle-pro/js/sticky-menu.js
```

So your `<script>` CODE should be:

```
<script data-cfasync="false" src="/wp-content/themes/lifestyle-pro/js/sticky-menu.js"></script>
```

## Bonus:

This can be made better with the use of the WordPress function [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/). In that case, your CODE will be:

```
<script data-cfasync="false" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/sticky-menu.js"></script>
```

An even better method is to use `wp_enqueue_script()` function in combination with `wp_enqueue_scripts` filter hook, as described [in this WordPress document](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer. I agree with you to take the whole wp-path or even the Bonus-version.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the solution is

1. De-activation of the plugin "**wordfence**", that didn't allow to write into the **head**-section.
2. Changing a code-snippet in the '**functions.php**' to get the 'sticky-menu.js' working. After this changing the script needn't put in into the **head**-section. I got the correct code-snippet for the 'functions.php' from [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/bgardner/5038210).